# Writing data to the Excel,showing Null pointer Exception

Tags: excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I am a beginner to the selenium WebDriver.
This is the part of my selenium code for writing data to the excel sheet,but while executing the code i am getting NullPointer Exception...what will be the reason..?(excel sheet is in closed state,No compiletime issue)

code:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx");

Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
Sheet sh=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

for(int i=0;i<=20;i++) {
    Row row=sh.getRow(i);

    for(int m=0;m<=20;m++) {
        Cell cell=row.createCell(m);

        cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue("good");

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx");

        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}

System.out.println("Excel File Written");
```

Comment: Hi please go through this http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi

Comment: Which object is null?

Comment: To avoid guesswork, could you attach the contents of the Excel file or upload it somewhere?

Comment: the exception is like:                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException..........Iam using empty excel file

Answer (score 2):

If the excel is completely blank then you will get null pointer exception so ensure there is some data in at least one cell before executing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You had accessed a row in xlsx file but it happens that row may be null, so replace getrow to createrow:

```
Row row=null;

for(int i=0;i<=20;i++) {
    if(sh.getRow(i) != null) {
        row = sh.getRow(i);}
    else {
        row = sh.createRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: .Now its working fine:)                                                                                                 could u please explain                                                                       Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
Sheet sh=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");..................here actually upcasting is happening right?

Comment: As I said in answer some of the rows were blank means they could be null, and you cannot access them directly without checking them if they are null. If you try to access null row directly, it will surely give null pointer exception. You have to create row there, then only you can create cell.